# How to change an image after a keyboard input in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, animation

I have the following code to show you:

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
     Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
     int x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0; 



public Test()
{
    tm.start(); //starts the timer
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); 
}




public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    ImageIcon s = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pictures\\Stick.jpg");
    s.paintIcon(this,g,x,y);

}




public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (x < 0)
    {
        velX = 0;
        x = 0;
    }

    if (x > 630)
    {
        velX = 0;
        x = 630;
    }

    if(y < 0)
    {
        velY = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    if(y > 430)
    {
        velY = 0;
        y = 430;
    }
    x = x + velX;
    y = y + velY;
    repaint();
}




public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int c = e.getKeyCode();

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        velX = -1;
        velY = 0;

    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = -1;

    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        velX = 1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 1;
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
}





public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test t = new Test();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
    jf.setSize(700, 600);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(t);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

My problem is I whenever the user holds the right arrow on the keyboard it changes an image, when the user lets go it goes back the the default image. Please tell me how to do that. I think it is a series of if statements in the Graphics class then calling them to the key input but I'm not quite sure. I am also using Eclipse. Thank You.

Comment: Don't read the image in the painting method. You should read the image in the constructor of your class. You want painting to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @camickr. So what do you mean? You want me to put the image in a new class or outside of the program. How would I call that to the keyEvents?

Comment: I suggested you read the image in the constructor of your class. Then you create an instance variable for the class that you can reference in the paintComponent() method of your class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details
2. Use the key bindings API instead of `KeyListener`, it will cause you less issues. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Essentially, you could just have a `Image` as a class instance field, which was painted by the `paintComponent` method.  When the key was pressed, you would change the image to the "move image" and when it was released, change it back to the "default image"

## Updated with example

[image: Walk the pony]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Mover {

        public enum Direction {

            LEFT, RIGHT, NONE;
        }

        public void setDirection(Direction direction);

        public Direction getDirection();

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Mover {

        private BufferedImage left;
        private BufferedImage right;
        private BufferedImage stand;

        private BufferedImage current;
        private Direction direction = Direction.NONE;
        private int xPos;
        private int yPos;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                left = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Left.png"));
                right = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Right.png"));
                stand = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Stand.png"));
                current = stand;
                xPos = 100 - (current.getWidth() / 2);
                yPos = 100 - (current.getHeight() / 2);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            bindKeyStrokeTo(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, "move.left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,   0, false), new MoveAction(this, Direction.LEFT));
            bindKeyStrokeTo(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, "stop.left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,   0, true), new MoveAction(this, Direction.NONE));

            bindKeyStrokeTo(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, "move.right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), new MoveAction(this, Direction.RIGHT));
            bindKeyStrokeTo(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, "stop.right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), new MoveAction(this, Direction.NONE));

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    updatePosition();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void bindKeyStrokeTo(int condition, String name, KeyStroke keyStroke, Action action) {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(keyStroke, name);
            am.put(name, action);
        }

        @Override
        public Direction getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        @Override
        public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        protected void updatePosition() {

            switch (getDirection()) {
                case LEFT:
                    current = left;
                    xPos -= 1;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    current = right;
                    xPos += 1;
                    break;
                case NONE:
                    current = stand;
                    break;
            }

            if (xPos < 0) {
                xPos = 0;
                current = stand;
            } else if (xPos + current.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                current = stand;
                xPos = getWidth() - current.getWidth();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(current, xPos, yPos, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Mover mover;
        private Mover.Direction direction;

        public MoveAction(Mover mover, Mover.Direction direction) {
            this.mover = mover;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mover.setDirection(direction);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am kind of new to all of this and I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Can someone just write me the code for it, I don't understand any of this. Please, I'm so lost.

Comment: I did write the code for it. Make sure you're reading the tutorials as well to understand what the code is doing.  All it does is has a single image which is always painted.  It then swaps the images it wants painted based on the input of the user

Comment: Yes I understand what the code does I try running it and I get a whole bunch of errors:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at Test$TestPane.<init>(Test.java:75)
 at Test$1.run(Test.java:41)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at

Comment: java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: So basically I don't really know whats wrong. I took your code and added my own pictures. It gave me this.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The image you're "trying" to load doesn't exist (hence `input==null`) and no, there isn't really a "simpler" way to do this that won't result in a thousand other problems (and believe me, I'm lazy, so I always look for simple)