# I can't get my 2d game object to move

Tags: java, arrays, swing

This is the code for my main code. I tried creating a package with the functions to check the keyboard actions, but it didn't work. So now both codes are under the same file as you see it. So far the program opens, I can see the circle, but it won't move either left or right. I have been at this for like 3hrs believe it or not.

EDIT: I just realized that the update function gets the data from a package named "input". That was before I put both classes under the same file name, but even when there was a class with a package named "gamesample.input.*, it still wasn't working.

```
package gamesample;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 

 /** 
 * Main class for the game 
 */ 
public class GameSample extends JFrame 
{        
    boolean isRunning = true; 
    int fps = 30; 
    int windowWidth = 500; 
    int windowHeight = 500; 

    BufferedImage backBuffer; 
    Insets insets; 
    InputHandler input; 

    int x = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
            GameSample game = new GameSample(); 
            game.run(); 
            System.exit(0); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method starts the game and runs it in a loop 
     */ 
    public void run() 
    { 
            initialize(); 

            while(isRunning) 
            { 
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

                    update(); 
                    draw(); 

                    //  delay for each frame  -   time it took for one frame 
                    time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time); 

                    if (time > 0) 
                    { 
                            try 
                            { 
                                    Thread.sleep(time); 
                            } 
                            catch(Exception e){} 
                    } 
            } 

            setVisible(false); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will set up everything need for the game to run 
     */ 
    void initialize() 
    { 
            setTitle("Game Tutorial"); 
            setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
            setResizable(false); 
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            setVisible(true); 

            insets = getInsets(); 
            setSize(insets.left + windowWidth + insets.right, 
                            insets.top + windowHeight + insets.bottom); 

            backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 
            input = new InputHandler(this); 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will check for input, move things 
     * around and check for win conditions, etc 
     */ 
    void update() 
    { 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) 
            { 
                    x += 5; 
            } 
            if (input.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) 
            { 
                    x -= 5; 
            } 
    } 

    /** 
     * This method will draw everything 
     */ 
    void draw() 
    {               
            Graphics g = getGraphics(); 

            Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 

            bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
            bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); 

            bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            bbg.drawOval(x, 10, 20, 20); 

            g.drawImage(backBuffer, insets.left, insets.top, this); 

    }
}
```

This is the keyboard code

```
package gamesample;

import java.awt.Component; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

/** 
 * Makes handling input a lot simpler 
 */ 
public class InputHandler implements KeyListener 
 {        
 boolean keys[];
    /** 
     * Assigns the newly created InputHandler to a Component 
     * @param c Component to get input from 
     */ 


    public InputHandler(Component c) 
    { 
            c.addKeyListener(this); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Checks whether a specific key is down 
     * @param keyCode The key to check 
     * @return Whether the key is pressed or not 
     */ 
    public boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode) 
    { 


            if (keyCode > 0 && keyCode < 256) 
            {  keys = new boolean [256];
                    return keys[keyCode]; 
            } 

            return false; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Called when a key is pressed while the component is focused 
     * @param e KeyEvent sent by the component 
     */ 
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    { boolean keys[];
            if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256) 
            { keys = new boolean [256];
                    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true; 
            } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Called when a key is released while the component is focused 
     * @param e KeyEvent sent by the component 
     */ 
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    { boolean keys[];
            if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256) 
            { keys = new boolean [256];
                    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false; 
            } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Not used 
     */ 
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics g = getGraphics();` IS NOT how custom painting should be done.  Swing uses a passive rendering algorithm, meaning your UI could be repainted at any time, for any number of reasons, many of which you don't have control over.  Swing is also double buffered by default, so if you actually use a `JPanel` and overrode it's `paintComponent` method, you'd get double buffering for free AND you'd be notified of any system related paint events.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Don't use `KeyListener`, it's too troublesome and the key bindings API solves all the issues that it has.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

Remember, Swing is a single threaded framework and is not thread safe.  This means that you should never block the event dispatching thread in any way (like using a never ending loops) and you should only ever update the UI from within the context of the EDT.

You "main loop" is in danger of doing both.  It's a fluke of the nature of the JVM that the code doesn't block the EDT, but it also means that you are violating the single threaded nature of Swing.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Normally, I'd use a Swing `Timer` for this kind of work, as it's call backs are synchronized within the context of the EDT, but you can use a `Thread`, but you will have to manually synchronize the updates back to the EDT.

If you want complete control over the painting process, you should be using a `BufferStrategy`, see [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details

As a [basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387154/how-to-change-an-image-after-a-keyboard-input-in-java/30387171#30387171) of the above concepts