# How to use KeyListener to paint different images?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener

this is just my JFrame file. I want to paint down.png when my character moves down, paint up.png when my character moves up, etc.  I've been browsing for some time, and I can't quite find a solution for my problem. If someone could either link me to an answer, or provide one, that would be great!

Here is my code:

```
package Michael;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyCanvas extends Canvas implements KeyListener
{
int myX = 100;
int myY = 100;

BufferedImage down;
{
    try
    {
        down = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/down.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage downrun;
{
    try
    {
        downrun = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/downrun.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage left;
{
    try
    {
        left = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/left.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage right;
{
    try
    {
        right = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/right.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage runleft;
{
    try
    {
        runleft = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/runleft.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage runright;
{
    try
    {
        runright = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/runright.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage swoosh;
{
    try
    {
        swoosh = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/swoosh.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage swordraise;
{
    try
    {
        swordraise = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/swordraise.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage up;
{
    try
    {
        up = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/up.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

BufferedImage uprun;
{
    try
    {
        left = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/uprun.png"));
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find image file.");
    }
}

public MyCanvas() // The MyCanvas constructor.
{
    this.setSize(600, 400);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setFocusable(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(down, myX, myY, 55, 55, null);
    g.drawImage(left, myX, myY, 55, 55, null);
    g.drawImage(right, myX, myY, 55, 55, null);
    g.drawImage(up, myX, myY, 55, 55, null);
} // I don't want to draw every image at the same time, I only want to draw 'up', when the charcter is moving up, etc.

public void moveIt(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            myY += 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            myY -= 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            myX -= 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            myX += 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:

    }

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    moveIt(e);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: The first answer is don't, use a `JPanel` and the key bindings API instead, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387154/how-to-change-an-image-after-a-keyboard-input-in-java/30387171#30387171) for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Are you sure there's no other way than with JPanel? Surely there is a way to do it with JFrame. My class hasn't advanced into JPanel and half the stuff you have in that example.

Comment: There are ways, all of them fraught with issues and problems which the Key Bindings API was designed to solve.  `java.awt.Canvas` is from an API which was replaced with the Swing (`JPanel`) API over 15 years ago, maybe you should let your instructor know that they are dealing with an API which simply no longer used in general practice

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright, I'll bring it up with him. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `Motion With Key Bindings` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). This examples shows how to do animation using `Key Bindings` (which is the better solution) not a KeyListener.

Understand the basic concept first because you will need to make changes:

1. The existing code moves a `Component`. You would want to change that to be a `JLabel (with an Icon)`.
2. When creating the Actions you currently just specify the x/y values you want the `Component` to move. Now you will need to create the Actions with the `x/y values AND an Icon`, so you can change the Icon to be painted with every direction change.
3. The `move(...)` method will need to be modified to accept the Icon and then change the Icon of the JLabel component.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive there is no way to do this in JFrame? No matter how inefficient it is? My class has only done JFrame and I'm almost certain this type of coding will be on the test.

Comment: @McGovno FYI: `JFrame` can support the key bindings API

Comment: @McGovno, `Are you absolutely positive there is no way to do this in JFrame?` - what do you mean do it in JFrame? The example does use a JFrame. It uses a JPanel for custom painting and addes is to the JFrame. You should be using a JPanel for Swing, not a Canvas.